# Enum issues in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to initialize an object and trying to understand a few quirks.  First, I want to partially initialize the object using the .  I am encountering some strange quirks with regard to enums.

Consider this type hierarchy:

```
enum CalcType {
  EXPRESS,
  EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED,
  COST_BASIS
}

interface Program {
  active: boolean;
  code: string;
  displayOrder: number;
  dpld: boolean;
  calcType: CalcType;
}

this.p = <Program> {
  active: false,
  displayOrder: 100,
  dpld: true,
  calcType: CalcType[CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED],     // Does not work in Angular!!
  //calcType: CalcType['1']       // Works, value is a string
  //calcType: CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED      // Works, value is the ordinal
};
```

When I try to create/initialize a new Program using the interface type if I populate the calcType attribute using CalcType[CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED] it works in JSBin Typescript without issues but refuses to work in Angular Typescript 2.6.1.  Any ideas why?  The error I get is the following:

```
Type '{ active: false; displayOrder: number; dpld: true; calcType: string; }' cannot be converted to type 'Program'.
  Property 'code' is missing in type '{ active: false; displayOrder: number; dpld: true; calcType: string; }'.
```

However, if I use CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED or CalcType['1'] it works fine.

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/bipofim/edit?js,console

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/enums-test

What am I missing here?  I should be able to use the Enum[ordinal] syntax to get the string value.  In addition why does it complain that fields are missing in some cases and not in others?

**EDIT:**

Here is the issue, the HTTP service de-serializes/serializes from JSON using the syntax, where resp is the HttpResponse:

```
 return resp.body as Program;
```

During the de-serialization the strings in the JSON are converted to the enum string equivalents and not their ordinals.  During serialization they expect String equivalents of enums otherwise they just get converted to numbers which the server does not understand.

So how do I get the JSON to translate enum fields based on either their string values or ordinals??

i.e. Downstream "EXPRESS" should convert to CalcType.EXPRESS or 1
Upstream CalcType.EXPRESS or 1 should convert to "EXPRESS"

Comment: The error is not related with calcType property. You should set code with this definition, or make code optionnal with: `code?: string `

Comment: yes, code is required but it does not give me the error if I use CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED or CalcType['1'], why not?

Answer (score 2):

This is primarily TypeScript problem. It will cause an error anywhere, not just in Angular. It works in JSBin because it ignores compilation errors.

There are two different problems here, with `calcType` and `code` properties.

The problem is that enum is used incorrectly here, and this can be detected with type checks.

`CalcType` enum is desugared to:

```
var CalcType;
(function (CalcType) {
    CalcType[CalcType["EXPRESS"] = 0] = "EXPRESS";
    CalcType[CalcType["EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED"] = 1] = "EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED";
    CalcType[CalcType["COST_BASIS"] = 2] = "COST_BASIS";
})(CalcType || (CalcType = {}));
```

It provides a map of property names and their respective numeric values and results in an object:

[image: enum]

However this is [numeric enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums), and enum values are supposed to be numbers.

This is type error, enum values are supposed to be numbers, while `CalcType[CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED]` is a string:

```
calcType: CalcType[CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED]
```

This just disables type checks:

```
calcType: CalcType['1']
```

This is the way enums are supposed to be used, so it works:

```
calcType: CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED
```

If you *should be able to use the Enum[ordinal] syntax to get the string value*, then [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) have to be used, and string values are supposed to be defined explicitly:

```
enum CalcType {
  EXPRESS = 'EXPRESS',
  ...
}
```

This way it's not really different than a plain object:

```
const CalcType = {
  EXPRESS: 'EXPRESS',
  ...
};
```

This error states that the object has no `code`, while it should exist in `Program`:

> Property 'code' is missing in type '{ active: false; displayOrder: number; dpld: true; calcType: string; }'.

Comment: How am I able to create the type of Program without supplying the code field if it's required?  Shouldn't I consistently get this error message if this is the case?  However the error disappears if I just use 

`calcType: CalcType['1']`

Also, the data returned from the HTTP service is cast using "as Program" syntax and it automatically sets the enums as strings not numbers.  The HTTP service that persists also expects them as strings.  The CalcType[CalcType.EXPRESS] should supply the equivalent string.

Comment: This is a weirdness that is caused by <Program> type assertion, possibly TS bug. You already specified `p: Program`, you don't need type assertions here. Remove <Program>, and type error will be as expected. If calcType should always be a string, then you're misusing numeric enum. Use string enum or plain object, as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

Change your interface to the following:

```
interface Program {
    active: boolean;
    code?: string;
    displayOrder: number;
    dpld: boolean;
    calcType: string;
}
```

**Full Answer**

I can't answer exactly why it's happening, but I can say how to fix some of your issues.

You've specified `Program` to have a non-optional parameter `code` which you then haven't supplied to `this.p`. If you make `code` optional (`code?: string;`), it makes your error message go away and then you get the *real* issue (which isn't actually an issue!).

As far as Typescript is concerned, both `CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED` and `CalcType['1']` return an object of type `CalcType`. `CalcType[CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED]`, however, has a return type of `string`. You are violating your `Program` interface by assigning a `string` to `calcType` instead of a `CalcType`. If you change it to be `calcType: string;` then the rest of your problems go away.

As for your saying that `CalcType[CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED]` isn't working, I have tested it in Typescript 2.61 and 2.71, and both times it has correctly equated to 'EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED' as a `string`.

Comment: I'm actually not violating the interface.  I would like to supply the numeric.  However the HTTP service returning it automatically de-serializes the values as strings.  When I log the returned object to the console I see the string not the integer.  However, if I use CalcType.EXPRESS_LESS_EARNED it is a number.  Enums should always be numbers but the framework auto converts to strings at least in the case of the "as XYZType" syntax.

Comment: Maybe your compiled/run-time code doesn't violate it but run-time variable types and TypeScript variable types have nothing to do with each other. At run-time the interface doesn't even exist anymore. The point is, you've told  TypeScript that it will be a `CalcType` but then later you're creating an object and assigning a value that TypeScript believes to be a `string` (whether it actually is a string is irrelevant, TypeScript infers that it is from your code).

Comment: at runtime calcType is a string because it is deserialized from JSON.  Similarly when I send the object back to the server it has to be converted to a string.  But at design time it will not allow me to assign strings to it due to type checking.  Is there a way to control the marshalling/unmarshalling of enums?

Comment: What's the problem with just saying that it's a string to begin with seeing as it _is_ a string?

Comment: the issue is that the interface types are part of a library that has already defined these fields as enums.  We may have to re-define these as a string index types or probably convert them to string enums.